# Подключение библиотеки vk-master к проекту C++

Tags: c++, vkontakte-api

Есть готовый [скелет проекта](https://blast.hk/attachments/6831/), к нему хочу подключить [VK SDK](https://github.com/Kolsha/VK/archive/master.zip) для С++. Я закинул папку vk-master в папку проекта и инклудировал файл api.h с curl.h, но при компиляции выдает ошибки на "неразрешенный внешний символ". 
Подключил я дальше все .h и .cpp файлы, .lib там нет. Проблема не решалась.
Уже 4 дня такая проблема, google не в силах решить мою проблему. Надеюсь на юзеров форума)

Comment: *"закинул ... в папку проекта"*, *"Подключил я дальше все .h и .cpp файлы"* - не делайте так, указывайте компилятору и линкеру где искать эти файлы.

Comment: A где указывать? Использую VS  2019

Comment: Так Вам  нужна  только папка src, или нет?

Comment: Ну да, чтобы я вызывал методы в своём проекте для работы с вк.

Comment: Ну тогда скопируйте только папку src

Comment: методы в src, мне надо их вызывать в sfplugin.

Comment: я сделал так, но при собрании ошибка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Comment: @EOF, при компиляции сначала выдает 4 ошибки на эту строку
"            return std::string(start + offset, std::min(length, max_length - offset));", хотя по сути тут все в порядке. По приколу убрал эту строку и дальше ошибки: error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: bool __thiscall VK::Client::auth(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class ...

Comment: А у Вас curl есть?

Comment: Да, я установил через nuget и подключил

Comment: Имеются ещё варианты ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробую объяснить концептуально суть вашей проблемы.

Библиотеки в C/C++ состоят из заголовочных файлов, где описываются интерфейсы и файлов реализации статические(*.lib|*.a)и/или динамические(*.dll|*.so) - скопилированый код. 
Так вот для "подключения" библиотеки Вам необходимо компилятору указать пути поиска заголовчных файлов. А для линковщика пути к библиотекам и сами библиотеки. Это все специфично для каждого компилятора.  Так же следует учитывать что подключая библиотеку A, которая имеет заивисимости B,C. Вам так же необходимо подключить и эти зависимости(Для MSVC порядок не критичен, в gcc нужно это учитывать). Все это указывается в системе сборки или в ручную(это справедливо для небольших или учебных проектов).

Конкретно в вашем случае система сборки и IDE это одно и тоже(MSVC маскирует работу с nmake или msbuild). Все это прописывается настройках проекта Visual Studio.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Ну начало мне известно, только я не могу понять где и как указывать эти пути до файлов. В свойствах проекта я ничего не нашел..

Answer (score 0):

надо добавить к проекту libcurl_imp.lib, которая часть пакета curl. в бинарнике curl её нет, нужно собрать самому из исходников